# How the order by clause works while using timestamp?

Tags: mysql

I have a table "tab1" which have a timestamp field "time1". Suppose the table has 1 million records. I have the following two test queries:

1. `select * from tab1 order by time1 desc limit 0,10`
2. `select * from tab1 order by time1 asc limit 0,10`

When we use timestamp,are the records stored in the db in the sorted order of timestamp or they have to be sorted prior to displaying the result set while using order by clause?

If sorting is done then out of query 1 and query 2, which one is faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `SELECTs` are equal speed, regardless of how the rows were inserted, and regardless of whether there is an `INDEX(time1)`.

Without an index starting with time1, either query will read the entire table and sort it.  Then it will deliver 10 rows.

Having `INDEX(time1)` will *greatly* speed up either query.  It will read the first (or last) 10 rows of the index, find the data (`*`) and deliver the rows.  (The details of finding the rows varies with MyISAM/InnoDB and with `PRIMARY KEY` / not.)

`TIMESTAMP` is irrelevant.  The above discussion applies to any datatype.

In defining an index *in MySQL*, the `DESC` keyword is recognized, but ignored.  All indexes are stored `ASC`.  However, and `ORDER BY .. DESC` is happy to traverse the index in reverse order.

Comment: i have no idea about how to use index(time1)

Comment: `ALTER TABLE tab1 ADD INDEX(time1);` -- this is likely to make both of your queries run faster.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` sorts the query results before they are returned to the client. It doesn't affect the order in the database. The fact that you're using time stamps is irrelevant.

There is no reason evident here to suppose that either query will be the faster. It depends on what indexing you have for the table.

Comment: It means that it will sort the enire records in the table,in our case it is 1 million records and then give the 10 sorted records?

Comment: @ParveezAhmed No, it means it will sort the 10 query results before they are returned to the client, as I already wrote above. It's hard to see why you would believe it would sort a million rows when it doesn't need to.

Comment: Indexing a column means the DB will create a B-tree (or some similar awesome data structure) based on that column and it uses that to find stuff in O(logn) time and read the data sorted by that column without any additional computation.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of storage engine / table type. Data in MyISAM tables is not stored in sorted order. Data in InnoDB tables is stored in the order of the primary key (aka [clustered index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html)).

In your example, sorting will be fastest if you:

- use an InnoDB table
- created a clustered index on the `time1` column (in ASC or DESC order)

The query that matches the sort order of the index (eg ORDER BY time1 ASC if your clustered index is also ordered ASC) will perform fastest.

Note: if values in `time1` column are not unique (or it's possible they are not unique), then you will need to create an ordinary (secondary) index on that column.

Comment: This is just an example table and I didn't use a primary key in that table. How do I create an ordinary or secondary index on that column?

Comment: @rosemary, have a look at [CREATE INDEX Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html)

Comment: In defining an index _in MySQL_, the `DESC` keyword is recognized, but ignored.  All indexes are stored `ASC`.  However, and `ORDER BY .. DESC` is happy to traverse the index in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

Data is sorted when the query is executed. So both querys should perform in similar time.

You can check the query plan, and will see one of the step is `sorting`.

You can improve the query speed creating one index for field `time1`